# Numpy Basics - How to Interpret [:,] in array access

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I have an nd-array A

```
A.shape

(2, 500, 3)
```

What's the difference between `A[:]` and `A[:,2]`

Coming from Python, the ',' in the array access is confusing me a lot.

Comment: the first just returns the original array, the latter will return you the Array with shape `(2,3)` so will skip the column or middle dimension, you could have just tried this

Comment: In case you're wondering how that maps to python, it calls `A.__getitem__((slice(None), 2))` (note extra parens).

Comment: What's the process of mental interpretation when encountering : and ,

Comment: @SenthilKumaran 1. select all elements from the first axis 2. select the third element from the second axis. 3. select all remaining elements from remaining axes (specific to numpy)

Comment: @Aaron: `__slice__` is not a thing, and `__getslice__` is deprecated/removed in all the versions of python that matter

Comment: @Eric my bad... I was mixing `slice()` and `__getslice__` in my brain... I have more coffee in front of me now.

Comment: numpy has a lot of logic built into it's ndarray class that allows `__getitem__` to be used with more complicated types (tuples of objects in this case). This allows slice notation to evolve from more than simple "this index points to this object" schemes. If you use `dis.dis` to inspect `lambda a: a[:,2]` you'll see that before applying the slice, it builds a tuple to send to the [subscription](https://docs.python.org/3.6/reference/expressions.html#subscriptions) operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The commas separate the subscripts for each dimension. So, for example, if the matrix `M` is defined as

```
M = np.array([[1, 2, 3],
              [4, 5, 6],
              [7, 8, 9]])
```

then `M[2, 1]` would be 8 (third row, second column).

The subscript for each dimension can also be a slice, where `:` represents a full slice, like a slice in normal Python sequences.  For example, `M[:, 2]` would select from every row the third column, which would be `[3, 6, 9]`.

Any additional dimensions for which a subscript is not provided are implicitly full slices.  In your example, `A[:,2]` is equivalent to `A[:, 2, :]`. If you consider the `(2, 500, 3)` shaped array to be two stacked matrices with 500 rows and 3 columns, then `A[:, 2, :]` would select from both matrices the third row (and every column of the third row), which should have a shape of `(2, 3)`.

Comment: This certainly isn't a full explanation, but I had the same mental block when first starting to use numpy, and it was not immediately obvious where to find an answer.  I certainly would have benefited from this post.

Comment: Thank you, @lehiester. This answer was helpful to me.

Answer (score 1):

When you have multidimensional NumPy arrays, the slicing operation `[]` can work if you provide tuple of `slice()` objects. If the number of tuples does not match your number of dimensions, this is equivalent to having a `slice(None)` (which abbreviates to `:`) in all the remaining dimensions. Note also that NumPy also accepts `...` which means "fill the rest of the dimensions with `:`" - which is especially useful if you want to "fill" the initial dimensions.

So to recapitulate the following expression give identical results on your `A` array of `A.ndim == 3`:

```
A[:, 2]
A[:, 2, :]
A[:, 2, ...]


A[slice(None), 2]
A[slice(None), 2, slice(None)]
A[(slice(None), 2) + tuple(slice(None) for _ in range(A.ndim - 2))]
```